# How to at Click Image in GRIDVIEW Then Show name in EditText from drawable NOT from GridView Name

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext, android-gridview

i have a problem in GridView, if im Click Image in GRIDVIEW Then Show name in EditText from drawable NOT from GridView Name. "NOT IMAGEVIEW Click BUT GRIDVIEW Image Click"

[Example Image Ilutration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSvTz.jpg)

grid_view.xml :

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<GridView
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="368dp"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>


<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
enter code here
```

ImageAdapter.Java

```
enter code here
package com.tes.butawarna;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.plat_ishihara_01, 
        R.drawable.plat_ishihara_02,
        R.drawable.plat_ishihara_04,
        R.drawable.plat_ishihara_05,
        R.drawable.plat_ishihara_07,
        R.drawable.plat_ishihara_08,
        R.drawable.plat_ishihara_09,
        R.drawable.plat_ishihara_10,
};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return imageView;
}
```

}

AndroidGridLayout.java

```
enter code here
package com.tes.butawarna;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {
String[] nama;
EditText namagambar;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    namagambar=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Training.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Show us your code thusfar.

Answer (score 0):

After starting activity, just show different layout. Just ImageView and TextView. 
The first editText1 is useless under the gridView. Put it in dofferent layout.

Comment: u have a example coding sir.. please help me.

Comment: Implement the Training.class activity and use layout containing just one ImageView and TextView